# What's the parameter for ngResource save() method's callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm refactoring my angular code from using $http to ngResource.

I used to have code like this in my service:

```
svc.login = function(username, password) {
            return $http.post(apiEndpoint + 'authenticate', {
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function(val) {
                console.log("user token:", val.data);
                svc.token = val.data;
            });
        };
```

The user token printed will be a jwt token. Now I try to refactor the code to something like this:

```
   svc.login = function(username, password) {
        svc.authenticateApi().post(apiEndpoint + 'authenticate', {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                function(val) {
                    console.log("user token:", val);
                    svc.token = val;
                },
                function(res) {
                    console.log("error:", res.status + " " + res.statusText);
                });

        };
```

However, it doesn't work because the parameter `val` passed to the first callback is no longer the token itself but a object which contains a string array like this:

[image]

What's the standard way to handle data returned from post method? (in this case post is defined the same as `save` on this resource)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue comes from transformRespose

> transformResponse – {function(data,
>   headersGetter)|Array.} – transform
>   function or an array of such functions. The transform function takes
>   the http response body and headers and returns its transformed
>   (typically deserialized) version. By default, transformResponse will
>   contain one function that checks if the response looks like a JSON
>   string and deserializes it using angular.fromJson. To prevent this
>   behavior, set transformResponse to an empty array: transformResponse:
>   []

try transforming your response into a json:

```
transformResponse: function (data) {
        return { token: angular.fromJson(data) }
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case, I've transfromResponse to []: 'post': {
                    method: 'POST',
                    transformResponse: []
                },
but the result is the same

Comment: I updated my answer. angular js has problems when the response is a string. try making it into a json, or changing the response sent by your backend

Comment: this works now, thanks! but can you pls explain why ngResource is designed this way? `get` method's success callback will be passed in the data itself, why `post`'s success callback passes in what seems like a $resource object? Am I using the post method in a wrong way here? this makes ngResource a lot less attractive than $http.

Comment: ngResource is designed for RESTful APIs that's why it works that way, it expects a certain response type. I suspect that your api is not RESTful, but your resource requests can always be customised to fit your api