# Why does $resource save() method's success callback not passed in response data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ngresource

I'm very confused by the behaviour of ngResource, when calling a **get** method, the success callback has plain response data:

```
svc.userApi().get({id:0})           
            .$promise.then(                                                     
                function(response) {                                            
                    console.log(response);                            
                });
```

Here `response` is whatever data returned by backend. However, if I use **save/post** method:

```
svc.authenticateApi().save({
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
            .$promise.then(
                function(val) {
                    console.log("user token:", val);
                });
```

the `val` in callback is not the data returned by backend after the post action, instead it's a resource object, with properties like `$promise` and `$resolved`, etc: [image]
To get the proper data I have to define a `transformResponse` option when defining `authenticateApi`. (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326985/whats-the-parameter-for-ngresource-save-methods-callback#) for detail). Why is ngResource designed this way?

For comparison, it's very straightforward when using `$http` for this:

```
svc.login = function(username, password) {
            return $http.post(apiEndpoint + 'authenticate', {
                username: username,
                password: password
            })
            .then(function(val) {
                console.log("user token:", val.data);
            });
        };
```

The `val.data` in success callback is again a plain response data:

[image]

Have I been using save/post the wrong way? In my use case how else would you get authentication token back after successfully authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like save is expecting an array, for some reason, instead of a string.

I recommend writing your own methods for the resource

```
    var UserResource = $resource('/users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        'get': {
            cache: cache,
            isArray: true
        },
        'saveUserDefinition': {
            method: 'POST',
            interceptor: interceptor,
            isArray: false
        },
        'updateUserDefinition': {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
```

I return the methods of the resource in a service

```
    function getAllUsers(params) {
        if (!params) {
            params = {};
        }
        return UserResource.get(params).$promise;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I think the image I attached confused you, I don't think response is a array, it's actually an object (i think it's a resource object, because it has $promise etc), i have updated the image.

Comment: $resource methods are going to wrap the returned object as a resource type with special properties so its expected to have the additional fields (such as $promise) so you can do things like `var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {user.abc = true;user.$save();});` I noticed youre using 'save()' apposed to '$save()'. What does authenticateApi look like?

Comment: Ah..you pointed to the right direction, i'm using a customised 'post' method, instead of default save, however, my post definition is simple as this: return $resource(apiEndpoint + 'authenticate', null, {
                'post': {
                    method: 'POST' } }); I have to define an extra transformResponse function in 'post' to make it work. If I don't define this 'post' function but uses save directly, it works, I suppose the default save defines transformResponse? I can't use $save in this case because I don't have a resource object yet. I don't call a get method.